# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - webpacker.yml running `rails s`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, rubygems

If I make a folder with  `rails new myproject`
then go in the folder and type `rails s`, I get this error:

```
Warning: the running version of Bundler (2.1.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (2.1.4). We suggest you to upgrade to the version that created the lockfile by running `gem install bundler:2.1.4`.
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    77: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    76: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    75: from /home/arian/projects/Arian-p1/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    74: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    73: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    72: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    71: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    70: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    69: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    68: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    67: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    66: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    65: from /home/arian/projects/Arian-p1/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    64: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
    63: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    62: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
    61: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    60: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    59: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    58: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    57: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    56: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    55: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    54: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    53: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    52: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    51: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    50: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    49: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    48: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    47: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    46: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    45: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    44: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    43: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    42: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    41: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    40: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    39: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    38: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    37: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
    36: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
    35: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    34: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
    33: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    32: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    31: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    30: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    29: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    28: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    27: from /home/arian/projects/Arian-p1/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    26: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    25: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    24: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    23: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    22: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    21: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    20: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    19: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    18: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    17: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    16: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    15: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    14: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    13: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    12: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:84:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    11: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker.rb:35:in `bootstrap'
    10: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:25:in `bootstrap'
     9: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in `refresh'
     8: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:83:in `load'
     7: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:51:in `public_manifest_path'
     6: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:47:in `public_output_path'
     5: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:43:in `public_path'
     4: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:84:in `fetch'
     3: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:88:in `data'
     2: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in `load'
     1: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in `read'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/arian/projects/Arian-p1/config/webpacker.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    76: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    75: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    74: from /home/arian/projects/Arian-p1/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    73: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    72: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    71: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    70: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    69: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    68: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    67: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    66: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    65: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    64: from /home/arian/projects/Arian-p1/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    63: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
    62: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    61: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
    60: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    59: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    58: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    57: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    56: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    55: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    54: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    53: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    52: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    51: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    50: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    49: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    48: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    47: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    46: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    45: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    44: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    43: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    42: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    41: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    40: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    39: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    38: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    37: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    36: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
    35: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
    34: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    33: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
    32: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    31: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    30: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    29: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    28: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    27: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    26: from /home/arian/projects/Arian-p1/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    25: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    24: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    23: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    22: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    21: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    20: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    19: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    18: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    17: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    16: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    15: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    14: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    13: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    12: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    11: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:84:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    10: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker.rb:35:in `bootstrap'
     9: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:25:in `bootstrap'
     8: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in `refresh'
     7: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:83:in `load'
     6: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:51:in `public_manifest_path'
     5: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:47:in `public_output_path'
     4: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:43:in `public_path'
     3: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:84:in `fetch'
     2: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:88:in `data'
     1: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:91:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:95:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found /home/arian/projects/Arian-p1/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/arian/projects/Arian-p1/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)
```

I installed bundler 2.1.4
I am running on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line of the stack trace tells you what to do

> Please run rails webpacker:install

Its missing the file `config/webpacker.yml` which gets created by the command `bundle exec rails webpacker:install`

Comment: from your first code No such file or directory

Comment: and your secend code say: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

Comment: You need to run this command from the root directory of your rails application. Please provide some more information about your directory/file structure if that doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Run `gem install bundler:2.1.4`. If that doesn't work, you could also try `gem update --system`.

Comment: While this is certainly not a bad advise, the bundler warning is not related to the error, its just a warning.

Comment: undefined method `rubyforge_project=' for class `Gem::Specification' (NameError)